# Combine multiple rows by summing up some of its columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have following data in my table:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+--+
| ProductName | PricePerPiece | CafeID | Quantity | TotalPrice | MemberID | OrderID |        OrderDate        | OrderTotal | ProductID |  |
+-------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+--+
| Coffee      |            10 |      1 |        1 |         10 |       20 |    1008 | 2016-06-01 02:38:47.113 |        196 |         1 |  |
| Mocha       |           152 |      1 |        1 |        152 |       20 |    1008 | 2016-06-01 02:38:47.113 |        196 |         4 |  |
| Pikachu     |            34 |      1 |        1 |         34 |       20 |    1008 | 2016-06-01 02:38:47.113 |        196 |         5 |  |
| Coffee      |            10 |      1 |        1 |         10 |       20 |    1009 | 2016-06-01 02:39:49.750 |         35 |         1 |  |
| Cappucino   |            25 |      1 |        1 |         25 |       20 |    1009 | 2016-06-01 02:39:49.750 |         35 |         3 |  |
+-------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+--+
```

I want a single row for a particular product in which its `Quantity` and `TotalPrice` are added together, giving following expected output:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+--+
| ProductName | PricePerPiece | CafeID | Quantity | TotalPrice | MemberID | OrderID |        OrderDate        | OrderTotal | ProductID |  |
+-------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+--+
| Coffee      |            10 |      1 |        2 |         20 |       20 |    1008 | 2016-06-01 02:38:47.113 |        196 |         1 |  |
| Mocha       |           152 |      1 |        1 |        152 |       20 |    1008 | 2016-06-01 02:38:47.113 |        196 |         4 |  |
| Pikachu     |            34 |      1 |        1 |         34 |       20 |    1008 | 2016-06-01 02:38:47.113 |        196 |         5 |  |
| Cappucino   |            25 |      1 |        1 |         25 |       20 |    1009 | 2016-06-01 02:39:49.750 |         35 |         3 |  |
+-------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+--+
```

I tried following query:

```
SELECT [ProductName], [PricePerPiece], [CafeID],
    SUM([Quantity]) AS [Quantity], SUM([TotalPrice]) AS [TotalPrice],
    [MemberID],[OrderID],[OrderDate],[OrderTotal],[ProductID]
    FROM [ProductOrders] GROUP BY [ProductID], [ProductName], [PricePerPiece], [CafeID], [MemberID], [OrderID], [OrderDate], [OrderTotal]
```

But its giving the same result just showing `Coffee` rows together but not adding up its `Quantity` and `TotalPrice`. Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Is `SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2)` invalid in [sql-server]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderTotal` has a different value for each of the `Coffee` rows.  You can choose to not select `OrderTotal`, or you can `SUM(OrderTotal)` as well.

Any distinct values that you select but aren't summing (or otherwise aggregating) will not group together.

On closer look: Same goes for `OrderDate` and `OrderID`.  Based on your expected output, you want to select `MIN(OrderID), MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderTotal)`

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I used `SUM(OrderTotal)` and it solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have too many columns in the `GROUP BY`.  I would suggest:

- `OrderID`
- `OrderDate`
- `OrderTotal`

This information does not seem necessary for your goal:

```
SELECT [ProductName], [PricePerPiece], [CafeID],
       SUM([Quantity]) AS [Quantity], SUM([TotalPrice]) AS [TotalPrice],
       [MemberID], [ProductID]
FROM [ProductOrders]
GROUP BY [ProductID], [ProductName], [PricePerPiece], [CafeID], [MemberID];
```

Answer (score 1):

The columns with different values in each row, like `OrderID`, `OrderDate` , looking at your expected result set I can assume you want the earliest record for that, just use the `MIN` function for them columns.

Also only the column that are in the select and not contained in any aggregate function must be in the `group by` clause, and you will get the results you are after.

```
SELECT [ProductName]
     , [PricePerPiece]
     , [CafeID]
     , SUM([Quantity])   AS [Quantity]
     , SUM([TotalPrice]) AS [TotalPrice]
     , [MemberID]
     , MIN([OrderID])    AS [OrderID]
     , MIN([OrderDate])  AS [OrderDate]
     , [OrderTotal]
     , [ProductID]
FROM [ProductOrders] 
GROUP BY [ProductName]
     , [PricePerPiece]
     , [CafeID]
     , [MemberID]
     , [OrderTotal]
     , [ProductID]
```

Comment: Thank you M.Ali. I didn't knew this about `Group` clause. Thanks a lot for the info. :)